# Have sed operate on variable instead of standard input or a file

Tags: regex, shell, variables, sed

There are many questions asking about how to use a variable within a sed pattern, for example: `sed "s/re/$VAR/" file`, but I want to perform a substitution *on* a variable. So far, I have been using `echo` to do this:

```
echo "$VAR" | sed 's/re/new/'
```

But, though this works, it seems messy. Is there a simpler/more elegant way of doing this in bash or zsh?

Comment: If it needs to be a regular expression, I don't think there is another way. For [simple replacements](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion-1) (in `bash`) you can do `echo ${VAR/match/replace}`

Comment: I agree witht sean, that's not messy, as it's the way to go. Or you can use specific shell tricks (for bash or zsh)

Comment: @zmo, eh? What Sean suggested (and I agree is not messy) is what you're calling "shell-specific tricks". (The specific PEs at hand are not actually bash and zsh specific at all -- rather, they're originally **ksh** behavior, dating back at least to ksh88, that bash and zsh are both compatible with. Notably, ksh88 predates the POSIX sh standard's publication, so even though the POSIX sh standard didn't include all the PEs that ksh did, their meaning is very well-established).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
sed 's/re/new' <<< "$var"
```

If you want to do that and update the variable you can do this:

```
var=$(sed 's/re/new' <<< "$var")
```

Comment: Ah, thank you, that works perfectly. I didn't know about `<<<`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use sed, you can use "[parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)" for search and replace within a parameter; quoting the Bash manual:

> ```
>  ${parameter/pattern/string}
> ```
>
> The *pattern* is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename
>   expansion. *Parameter* is expanded and the longest match of *pattern*
>   against its value is replaced with *string*.
>
> If *pattern* begins with `/`, all matches of *pattern* are replaced
>   with *string*. Normally only the first match is replaced. If *pattern*
>   begins with `#`, it must match at the beginning of the expanded value
>   of *parameter*. If *pattern* begins with `%`, it must match at the end
>   of the expanded value of *parameter*.
>
> If *string* is null, matches of *pattern* are deleted and the `/`
>   following *pattern* may be omitted. If *parameter* is `@` or `*`, the
>   substitution operation is applied to each positional parameter in
>   turn, and the expansion is the resultant list. If *parameter* is an
>   array variable subscripted with `@` or `*`, the substitution operation
>   is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is
>   the resultant list.

Parameter expansion is not limited to this kind of substitution, there are many more, see the manual.

**A few examples**

Leaving away quoting for readability.

1. Simple variables

   ```
   $ var='abcabc'
   $ echo ${var/a/X}   # Replace first 'a'
   Xbcabc
   $ echo ${var//a/X}  # Replace all 'a'
   XbcXbc
   $ echo ${var/a}     # Remove 'a'
   bcabc
   $ echo ${var//a}    # Remove all 'a'
   bcbc
   $ echo ${var/#b}    # Try to remove 'b' from start of string - no-op
   abcabc
   $ echo ${var/#a}    # Remove 'a' from start of string
   bcabc
   $ echo ${var/%b}    # Try to remove 'b' from end of string - no-op
   abcabc
   $ echo ${var/%c}    # Remove 'c' from end of string
   abcab
   ```
2. Positional parameters

   ```
   $ set -- abcabc defdef abcabc # Set $1, $2 and $3
   $ echo ${@/a/X}               # Replace first 'a' for each parameter
   Xbcabc defdef Xbcabc
   $ echo ${@//a/X}              # Replace all 'a' for each parameter
   XbcXbc defdef XbcXbc
   $ echo ${@/?/X}               # Replace first occurrence of any character
   Xbcabc Xefdef Xbcabc
   $ echo ${@//?/X}              # Replace all characters
   XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX
   ```
3. Arrays

   ```
   $ arr=(abcabc defdef abcabc) # Create array
   $ echo ${arr[@]/a/X}         # Replace first 'a' in each element
   Xbcabc defdef Xbcabc
   $ echo ${arr[@]//a/X}        # Replace all 'a' in each element
   XbcXbc defdef XbcXbc
   $ echo ${arr[@]/?/X}         # Replace first character in each element
   Xbcabc Xefdef Xbcabc
   $ echo ${arr[@]//?/X}        # Replace all characters in all elements
   XXXXXX XXXXXX XXXXXX
   ```
4. Combinations

   These can also be combined:

   ```
   $ arr=(patxxx xxpatxx xxxpat)  # Create array
   $ echo ${arr[@]/pat/X}         # Replace 'pat' in each element
   Xxxx xxXxx xxxX
   $ echo ${arr[@]/%pat/X}        # Replace 'pat' if it matches at the end
   patxxx xxpatxx xxxX
   $ echo ${arr[@]/#pat/X}        # Replace 'pat' if it matches at the beginning
   Xxxx xxpatxx xxxpat
   ```
5. Extended pattern matching

   Together with [extended patterns](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching), parameter expansion for search and replace becomes quite powerful:

   ```
   $ printf -v var "%b" ' have_spaces\t'     # Has space and tab
   $ echo "$var" | cat -A                    # Show whitespace
    have_spaces^I$
   $ shopt -s extglob                        # Turn on extended pattern matching
   $ echo "${var//+([[:space:]])}" | cat -A  # Remove all whitespace
   have_spaces$
   ```

   The example is somewhat contrived as the same problem could be solved simpler – the point is that it's pretty flexible.

Comment: Thanks, that works for simple things, but is there a way to do something like `sed 's/re/new/g' <<<"$VAR"`

Comment: `pattern` is not treated as a regular expression, it is a glob.

Comment: @Samadi That would be `${VAR//re/new}`, I've added a few examples.