# Script to add a user to vncserver config file

Tags: bash, vnc

I want to write a bash script to automatically add a user to the `vncserver` config file. According to the Centos [guide](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/VNC-Server#head-4d3002833b106148eb6e5013b0a8cdccaf3a6cec), I have to edit `/etc/sysconfig/vncserver` and

1. expand the first line from `VNCSERVERS="1:user1"` to `VNCSERVERS="1:user1 2:user2"`
2. append a line for the new user (second user in the example) `VNCSERVERARGS[2]="-geometry 1250x700"`

Therefore, by running `./add_user_to_vnc user2`, the content of the original file will be updated from

```
VNCSERVERS="1:user1"
VNCSERVERARGS[1]="-geometry 1250x700"
```

to

```
VNCSERVERS="1:user1 2:user2"
VNCSERVERARGS[1]="-geometry 1250x700"
VNCSERVERARGS[2]="-geometry 1250x700"
```

Two hard parts of such a script (for me) is to maintain a counter and expand the first line. Appending the last line should be fairly simple with `echo >>` command!

Any idea for that?

Comment: Should your script work for the general case of going from *n* users to *n* + 1 users?

Comment: Yes because I can not remember the last user's number

Comment: That would make the most sense. Parse the `VNCSERVERS` line, isolate the last user with *paramete-expansion*, get the user number and then append the new to that line (with `sed`) and you can make a second call to `sed` to finish the addition of the `VNCSERVERARGS` line. (my money is on Benjamin's solution, if he doesn't do one, I'll help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get new user name
new_user="$1"

# Get list of current users
servers="$(grep 'VNCSERVERS' vncserver)"

# Extract counter of last user
users="${servers#*\"}"      # Remove everything up to first quote
last_user="${users##* }"    # Remove everything up to last space
ctr="${last_user%%:*}"      # Remove everything starting from colon

# Increase counter
(( ++ctr ))

# Remove trailing quotes from line with current users
servers="${servers%\"}"

# Construct new first line
printf -v servers "%s %d:%s\"" "$servers" "$ctr" "$new_user"

# Construct new line for server args
serv_args="VNCSERVERARGS[$ctr]=\"-geometry 1250x700\""

# Use sed to replace first line and append last line
sed '1s/.*/'"$servers"'/;$a\'"$serv_args"'' vncserver
```

Remarks:

- This prints the new file to stdout. To update your `vncserver` file, you have to

  - either redirect to a temporary file and then rename that file (notice that `./script > vncserver` would truncate the file before processing it and you'd end up with an empty file)
  - or update the sed line to use `sed -i` (or for BSD sed: `sed -i''`) for in-place processing. To keep a backup file, use `sed -i.bak`.
- Some seds require a newline after the append command `a\`; the sed command would then become

  ```
  sed '1s/.*/'"$servers"'/;$a\
  '"$serv_args"'' vncserver
  ```
- Extracting the counter feels a bit bulky, but it has to account for the possibility of only one user being in the list and thus no spaces. I'm pretty sure more elegant solutions are possible.

Example usage (with `sed -i`):

```
$ cat vncserver
VNCSERVERS="1:user1"
VNCSERVERARGS[1]="-geometry 1250x700"
$ ./SO.sh user2
$ cat vncserver
VNCSERVERS="1:user1 2:user2"
VNCSERVERARGS[1]="-geometry 1250x700"
VNCSERVERARGS[2]="-geometry 1250x700"
$ ./SO.sh another_user
$ cat vncserver
VNCSERVERS="1:user1 2:user2 3:another_user"
VNCSERVERARGS[1]="-geometry 1250x700"
VNCSERVERARGS[2]="-geometry 1250x700"
VNCSERVERARGS[3]="-geometry 1250x700"
$ ./SO.sh latest_user
$ cat vncserver
VNCSERVERS="1:user1 2:user2 3:another_user 4:latest_user"
VNCSERVERARGS[1]="-geometry 1250x700"
VNCSERVERARGS[2]="-geometry 1250x700"
VNCSERVERARGS[3]="-geometry 1250x700"
VNCSERVERARGS[4]="-geometry 1250x700"
```

Comment: Only validation tweak I would have is `((ctr++)) || { printf "error: invalid 'ctr' value '%s'.\n" "$ctr"; exit 1; }` (just to insure bad info doesn't get written to the config file) Always did like the capable string handling of bash... (Oh, and I think `user1`, etc.. would need to be taken from a positional parameter -- I doubt that vncserver users literal `user1` as the actual name `:)`

Comment: @David Oh, an oversight... Have to update for positional parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much. One more question: How does `users="${servers#*\"}"` and similar lines are interpreted? I mean where can I find the definition of `#*`, `##*` and ...? Are they related to regex? I haven't seen them before

Comment: @mahmood These are called "parameter expansions" and quite a powerful way to manipulate strings. See [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), the [Bash Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe), or [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35920314/have-sed-operate-on-variable-instead-of-standard-input-or-a-file/35920527#35920527).